# multithreading with database

Tags: c#, .net, database, multithreading, transactions

I am looking out for a strategy to utilize multithreading (probably asynchronous delegates) to do a synchronous operation. I am new to multithreading so i will outline my scenario first. This synchronous operation right now is done for one set of data (portfolio) based on the the parameters provided. The (psudeo-code) implementation is given below:

```
public DataSet DoTests(int fundId, DateTime portfolioDate)
{
    // Get test results for the portfolio
    // Call the database adapter method, which in turn is a stored procedure,
    // which in turns runs a series of "rule" stored procs and fills a local temp table and returns it back.
    DataSet resultsDataSet = GetTestResults(fundId, portfolioDate);

    try 
    {

        // Do some local processing on the results
        DoSomeProcessing(resultsDataSet);

        // Save the results in Test, TestResults and TestAllocations tables in a transaction.

        // Sets a global transaction which is provided to all the adapter methods called below
        // It is defined in the Base class
        StartTransaction("TestTransaction");    

        // Save Test and get a testId
        int testId = UpdateTest(resultsDataSet);    // Adapter method, uses the same transaction

        // Update testId in the other tables in the dataset
        UpdateTestId(resultsDataSet, testId);

        // Update TestResults
        UpdateTestResults(resultsDataSet);          // Adapter method, uses the same transaction

        // Update TestAllocations
        UpdateTestAllocations(resultsDataSet);      // Adapter method, uses the same transaction

        // It is defined in the base class
        CommitTransaction("TestTransaction");
    }
    catch
    {
        RollbackTransaction("TestTransaction");
    }
        return resultsDataSet;
}
```

Now the requirement is to do it for multiple set of data. One way would be to call the above `DoTests()` method in a loop and get the data. I would prefer doing it in parallel. But there are certain catches:

- `StartTransaction()` method creates a connection (and transaction) every time it is called.
- All the underlying database tables, procedures are the same for each call of `DoTests().` (obviously).

Thus my question are:

- Will using multithreading anyway improve performance?
- What are the chances of deadlock especially when new TestId's are being created and the Tests, TestResults and TestAllocations are being saved? How can these deadlocked be handled?
- Is there any other more efficient way of doing the above operation apart from looping over the `DoTests()` method repeatedly?

Comment: Have you profiled the application to see where the application is slow? If actually saving to the database is your slow point, then multithreading won't gain you anything.

Comment: No I haven't profiled it yet, but theoretically even if there is no performance gain as such, then can this operation be called asynchronously without changing the underlying mechanism of this method?
Would i need to change (or rewrite) the above method in a different way just to support multithreading?

Comment: Don't confuse multithreading with asynchronicity. Multithreading is one method to implement asynchronicity, but they aren't the same thing. Do you want asynchronous processing in general, or specifically multithreaded processing?

Comment: I am sorry if my reply was causing some confusion. I was going to implement this particular case using asynchronous delegates. Which if i am correct is way of utilizing thread pool. i was just looking for a view from the experts like you, if it is possible in this case and what can be the pitfalls as well as amount of changes required to implement it.
Thanks.

Comment: I've found datasets to be very inefficiency when using them as a read-only array. Better off loading your data into an array of objects, assuming you don't need certain dataset features. The next thing is you're going to have to make sure your transaction isolation is set to row level, otherwise it will lock the table, which will force serialization and defeat any threading. Are you actually updating those other tables or inserting new entries? If the testid column that you're updating has an index on it, the DB may cause some serialization because updates will force index updates

Comment: Thanks for some of the clarifications. I am using dataset to bind (by using BindingSource) with the grids on a Winform application. So basically they are being used to perform all CRUD operations.
I was suspecting that each transaction will lock the tables, in way defeating the main purpose, that is why these question. All the updates (UpdateTest, UpdateTestResults and UpdateAllocations) do only CUD operations, but in this particular case they will only be doing Inserts as the all the concerned rows in the datatables will have there RowState as Added.

Comment: Just one question. How can  transaction isolation level be set to Row level?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I completely understand what you mean.
1. Yes if you call `DoTests` several times on different threads your code performance will be better. Assuming you don't get locked inside your `GetTestResults` and `UpdateXXX` methods.
2. This basically depends on your implementation of methods you call ( `GetTestResults` and `UpdateXXX` methods)
3. You were going to call several `DoTests` simultaneously, correct? So why do you ask about plain looping?

Actually I did not get you completely about transactions. To my understanding each instance will you use its own transaction, correct? Otherwise I believe you run into troubles serializing updates of transaction.

Comment: Thanks. I think i get it where the problems might lie. 1. and 2. As GetTestResults and UpdateXXX are not static method but something like TestLogicObject.GetTestResults and XXXAdapterObject.UpdateXXX so they are not shared between threads. 3. I was planning to call XXXLogic.DoTests simultaneously so each thread would create a new instance of XXXLogic, thus each instance would have a separate DoTest method and thus separate transaction in it.